# Show $ \mathbb{E}(T_1\mid N_1=0)=1+\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for a Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-process

For a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, show $ \mathbb{E}(T_1\mid N_1=0) = 1 + \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

**attempt**

We know $T_1 \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$.

The solution I'm looking at says to use the memoryless property. I don't see how it fits. All I see is that $\{N_1 =0\}=\{T_1>1\}$. So I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\operatorname E(T_1\mid T_1>1) = 1 + \operatorname E(T_1) \text{ by memorylessness.}
$$
$$
= 1 + \frac 1 \lambda.
$$

Comment: can you please elaborate on how exactly memoryless was used?

Comment: @veritas : The conditional distribution of $T_1-t$ given that $T_1>t$ is the same as the (marginal, or unconditional) distribution of $T_1.$ That is memorylessness. Hence $\operatorname E(T_1-t\mid T_1>t) = \operatorname E(T_1) = 1/\lambda. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $E(T_1\mid N_1=0)=\int_0^\infty P(T_1 >t\mid N_1=0) \, dt$. For $t<1$ the integrand is $0$ so this becomes $\int_1^\infty P(T_1 >t\mid T_1>1) \, dt$. Now use the memoryless property.

Comment: thanks for the response but still unsure how to apply the memoryless property here since $\{T_1>t|T_1>1\}$ isn't of the form $\{T_1>t+s|T_1>s\}$. I can only think since $t>1$ then I can write $t=1+s, s>0$ then $\{T_1>t|T_1>1\}=\{T_1>1+s|T_1>1\}=\{T_1>s\}$